# Expression Language that has libraries for Java and .NET

Tags: library, java, c#, cross-platform, programming

I'm looking for an expression language that I can use in both Java and .NET projects. My project uses a java server and a C# UI, and we want to be able to create simple expressions that can be both parsed and executed in both languages.

It needs to have the following features:

- Basic arithmetic: */+-
- Variables and Literals
- Boolean operators: AND, OR, NOT
- Set membership functions (IN)
- Complex Expressions e.g. (A+5 > X OR !B) AND Pow(C, 2) < 100
- Parses into an AST
- lightweight language specific for single line expressions (i.e. not Python, JavaScript etc.)

Nice to have would be:

- General Set functions: Union/Intersection/Complement
- Math/Trig functions
- User defined functions (defined in Java or C#)
- Array and Map support

I need the AST so that I can 1) translate the expressions into another language (SQL) and 2) display the expression tree graphically.

The closest I have found is Spring EL (http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html, http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), but its unclear to me if the Java and .NET versions are compatible.